# Class 'Abodeo\LaravelStripe\LaravelStripeServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am running a Laravel 4.2 application.

I have a local environment using Homestead and Vagrant.  And a live server using AWS ubuntu EC2 and Laravel Forge.

On my local environment I have set up the Abodeo - Laravel Stripe package using the instructions seen here: https://github.com/Abodeo/laravel-stripe

However, when pushing my project live, something is lost in translation and I am receiving the following error:

```
Class 'Abodeo\LaravelStripe\LaravelStripeServiceProvider' not found
```

I have added `'Abodeo\LaravelStripe\LaravelStripeServiceProvider'` to my app/config file and I ran `composer install/composer dump-autoload` on the live server.  Still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

make sure in composer.json like this

```
"require": {
        "abodeo/laravel-stripe": "dev-master"

    },
```

and then run

```
composer update abodeo/laravel-stripe
```

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Abodeo\LaravelStripe\LaravelStripeServiceProvider' not found

 /home/forge/default/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php - line 158

Comment: 1. try this command for debug
 composer dumpautoload -vvv
2. after run the command, let check in
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php

Comment: Ok I understood the first part, I ran the composer dumpautoload -vvv command, but I don't understand the second part

Comment: output was this: Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Generating autoload files

Comment: Anything else to help?